# Preselect the dropdowns on the UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my application UI, I have a the following fields: datepicker to display the date, hours dropdown, minutes dropdown, and am/pm dropdown.

The ViewModel is returning a datetime value, based upon which I set the dropdowns :

```
 function setSelectedIndex(s, valsearch) {
        // Loop through all the items in drop down list
        for (i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++) {
            if (s.options[i].value == valsearch) {
                // Item is found. Set its property and exit
                s.options[i].selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

        setSelectedIndex($("#ScheduledHour"), '<%= Model.Scheduled.Value.Hour %>');
        setSelectedIndex($("#ScheduledMinute"), '<%= Model.Scheduled.Value.Minute %>');
```

and here is the markup:

```
<select id="ScheduledHour" name="ScheduledHour" >
                        <option value="1">1 </option>
                        <option value="2">2 </option>
                        <option value="3">3 </option>
                        <option value="4">4 </option>
                        <option value="5">5 </option>
                        <option value="6" >6 </option>
                        <option value="7">7 </option>
                        <option value="8">8 </option>
                        <option value="9">9 </option>
                        <option value="10">10 </option>
                        <option value="11">11 </option>
                        <option value="12">12 </option>                       
                    </select></li>
```

Model.Scheduled.Value.Hour and Model.Scheduled.Value.Minute is returning the correct values but they are not being set on the UI. Any suggestions on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#ScheduledHour").val("<%= Model.Scheduled.Value.Hour %>");
$("#ScheduledMinute ").val("<%= Model.Scheduled.Value.Minute %>");
```

**jQuery:**

**.val( value )**

Description: Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
value: A string of text or an array of strings corresponding to the value of each matched element to set as selected/checked.
```

**.val()**

Description: Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: This works. But the hour value coming back is in 24 hr format. How can I convert this into a 12 hr format to display on the UI?

Answer (score 1):

is doing:

```
$('#ScheduledHour option[value="<%= Model.Scheduled.Value.Hour %>"]').attr("selected", "selected");

$('#ScheduledMinute option[value="<%= Model.Scheduled.Value.Minute %>"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```

out of the question?? I appreciate it's a jquery based solution, but you hav included that tag, so seems appropriate.